# SQL MAX Date Getting Last Transction between dates

Tags: sql, database, date, parameterized-query

I'd like to get the last transaction for a cardnumber between a given date with additional criteria.

```
Select * from table WHERE date <= '6/30/2012' and Type = 'D'
```

Data:

```
CardNumber   FirstName      Date           Type
1            John           11/01/2013     F
1            John           10/14/2013     D
1            John           05/01/2012     D
2            Paul           04/01/2012     D
2            Paul           05/15/2013     F
2            Paul           01/01/2012     D
```

Result:

```
CardNumber   FirstName      Date      
1            John           05/01/2012     D
2            Paul          04/01/2012     D
```

Comment: `SELECT CardNumber, FirstName, MAX(Date), Type FROM table WHERE Date <= '6/30/2012' AND Type = 'D' GROUP BY CardNumber, FirstName, Type` should work, but there may be better (more efficient) ways to achieve the result you're looking for.

Comment: I think this one is more efficient: Select TOP 1 * from table WHERE date <= '6/30/2012' and Type = 'D' ORDER BY Date Desc

Comment: @cha - You should post that as an answer.  I agree that it would seem to be more efficient than my suggestion.

Comment: Neither Worked. Tims returns the latest record for dates before 6/30/2012, but skips any dates in 2013. I want it to not return anything of there has been a transaction past 6/30/2013. Cha returns one record, I really need the entire list.

Comment: Tim's answer should be the correct one based on your requirements. But to exclude records for a card where there are transactions past a certain date you should use something like a WHERE NOT EXISTS statement. And most likely remove the WHERE data <= '6/30/2012' part.